# How to count number of products in category that have tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried doing WP_Query count and "get_terms" but was eventually unable to combine a script that would count wordpress woocommerce products in specific category that have specific tag.
I think Woocommerce products are just custom taxonomy posts.

Here is an example on how i count number of posts in product category:

```
$zz = get_term_by( 'id', $cat_id, 'product_cat' );
echo $zz->count;
```

Above gives result of products in category by category id. Now how do I count only those products in specific category that have for example tag "something". My guess would be that I have to use some query but how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do a [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'product_cat' => 'some_category_slug',
    'product_tag' => 'some_tag_slug'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$count = $query->post_count;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I had a feeling that WP_querry is the thing I should use but at first I used wrong post_type, didn't noticed that error and that got me confused. Thank you!

Comment: This is very expensive if you just need to run this for the purpose of a post count. Add `'fields' => 'ids',` to your arguments to just get post ID's. This way, your query is 1000 times faster and very lean ;-)